# How to make conditional multi-selection question in MS Forms?

Tags: forms, power-automate

I have created five questions in my MS form. Q1 is a single selection question with options: 'Middle School, High School, and College/University'. If a user select 'Middle School', then the multi-selection Q2 only shows a list of middle school courses. Q3 ~ Q5 are the same questions no matter which choice the user makes for Q1.

Since the course list for each educational level in Q1 has more than 10 items, I cannot make the Q2 a very long list to include all the courses from each educational level.

I also need to record the form response to a SharePoint site. If I split the Q2 into 3 different questions, I can use 'branch' function to set this logic, but it will be difficult to track the form response into the SharePoint site.

Any ideas or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.